# I have a thread 1 signal sigabrt error, but I don't think it is about storyboard

Tags: objective-c

I am new on objective-C, I am looking other people's code and try to rewrite it ,but I keep getting thread 1 signal sigabrt error. I don't think it is about storyboard, because this project doesn't use it, almost everything only make by programming code.

it happen when I open APP, type account and password, try to login, post and get return data, the error come out! seem like I get return nothing or fail.

i don't used to see objective block before, but I am sure problem always happen on this line.

```
 if (success) {
       success(responseObject)
 }
```

hope someone can give me any idea to think this problem!! thanks a lot.

```
+(void)post:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(id)parameters success:(void (^)(id))success failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failure{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *session = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [session POST:URLString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        if (success) {
            success(responseObject);
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure(error);
        }
    }];   
}
```

Crash log:

> 2016-10-17 18:49:17.487 chongBa[23417:383815] -canOpenURL: failed for
>   URL: "weixin://app/wx37c8011ed84267db/" - error: "(null)" 2016-10-17
>   18:49:17.492 chongBa[23417:383815] Reachability Flag Status: -R
>   ------- networkStatusForFlags 2016-10-17 18:49:17.496 chongBa[23417:383815] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "sinaweibo://" -
>   error: "(null)" 2016-10-17 18:49:17.496 chongBa[23417:383815]
>   -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "sinaweibohd://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme sinaweibohd" 2016-10-17 18:49:17.528
>   chongBa[23417:383815]  INFO: Reveal Server started (Protocol Version
>   25). 2016-10-17 18:50:04.191 chongBa[23417:383815] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '***
>   -[**NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cc24d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010c231deb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010cbcc885 -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:] + 101     3   chongBa
>
>   0x00000001080d1ce6 __39-[PBLoginRegisterViewController
>   login:]_block_invoke_3 + 102  4   chongBa
>
>   0x00000001080f5480 __46+[PBHttpTool
>   post:parameters:success:failure:]_block_invoke + 112  5   chongBa
>
>   0x0000000108086514 __116-[AFHTTPSessionManager
>   dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:URLString:parameters:uploadProgress:downloadProgress:success:failure:]_block_invoke.97
>   + 228     6   chongBa                             0x00000001080a7b19 __72-[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke_2.152 + 201    7
>
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d296d9d
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d2b73eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8     9   libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000010d29f1ef _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738   10 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb7e0f9
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb3fb99 __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2073    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb3f0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488   13  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010d798ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  14  UIKit
>   0x000000010acb5f09 UIApplicationMain + 171    15  chongBa
>   0x000000010802287f main + 111     16  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010d2eb92d start + 1  17  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: I edit my question and post the crash log. I used postman to test API, looks like API is working.

Comment: The crash is being caused by an array being sent out of bounds. Can you put in an exception breakpoint and see if it's stopping at the same location in the code?

Answer (score 0):

> error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme

Error above may be suggest to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` scheme entry in .plist for URL you are querying:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>YourScheme</string>
</array>
```

Hope this will help:)